# Using subquery in laravel to find count of a product type in same tables with multiple where conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

My question may not be clear, if you cannot understand please mention.

This is the complete structure of the table

[image]

**Issue**

1. Get count of all applications for the user
2. Remove first five applications from the select and get remaining count of it.
3. In the above output's count need to filter type of product and get count for each product type.

**Code Tried**

```
$res_applications_count = CreateApplicationModel::where('rs_users_id', $sub_user_id)
    //->skip($skip)
    ->take($limit)
    ->where([
        ['application_status', '!=', 'Not Submitted'], 
        ['application_status', '!=', 'InProgress']
    ])
    ->whereBetween('created', [$sub_start_date, $sub_end_date])
    ->where('product_type', '=', "Residential")
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->count();
```

Need to get different product types count after discounting the allowed limit from overall count of the user's application. for ex 5 counts to be removed from 100 applications and check remaining 95 for product types.

**Expected Ans**

Total count - 100
Discount - 5
Remaining- 95

In Remaining get count of different types:

First type - 50
Second type - 20
Third Smooth - 25

Comment: you're right its very unclear, i cant tell where `application_status` comes from. You are also doing a count on a collection instead of an SQL count.

Comment: what about the issue, do u mean you want to get those three issues' result?

Comment: @prakashg still unclear, I think may be u can write an example output for us, so we can know what fields u want, what structure do it look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but here is the user's applications count by `product_type` and skipping first `$skip` numbers of results:

```php
$applications_count_by_product_type = CreateApplicationModel::where('rs_users_id', $sub_user_id)
    ->skip($skip)
    ->groupBy('product_type')
    ->count();
```